# Accidentally made a directory "~" in a subdirectory

Tags: rm

I accidentally made a directory "~/" under a subdirectory in my home directory. How to safely remove this directory without affecting my home directory. `rm -r ~` obviously won't work... Thanks!

Comment: Did u try rm -r ~/path/to/~

Answer (score 5):

When placed in quotes, `~` is never expanded.  So:

```
rm -r '~'
```

Similarly, tilde expansion is not performed unless the tilde is first character.  So, this will also work:

```
rm -r ./~
```

#### Safer approach for removing empty directories

`rm -r` will remove a directory and all its contents.  If you only want to delete a directory if it is empty, then use `rmdir` instead (Hat tip: Patrick).  In this case:

```
rmdir '~'
```

Or,

```
rmdir ./~
```

#### Documentation

> **Tilde Expansion**
>    If a **word begins with an** **unquoted** **tilde
>   character** (`~`), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted 
>   slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are
>   considered a tilde-prefix.   If  none  of  the   characters  in  the 
>   tilde-prefix  are  quoted,  the characters in the tilde-prefix
>   following the tilde are  treated as a possible login name.  If this
>   login name is the null string, the tilde is  replaced  with  the
>   value of the shell parameter HOME.  If HOME is unset, the home
>   directory of the user executing the shell is  substituted instead. 
>   Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory
>   associated  with  the  specified login name. [Emphasis added.]

Comment: "rm -f" will not remove a directory...

Comment: @ThomasDickey Oops: typo corrected.

Comment: It would be MUCH safer to use `rmdir`, not `rm -r`. Since the directory was just created, it should be empty.

Comment: @Patrick Very good point.  Answer updated with `rmdir`.

Answer (score 0):

The command `rm -ir -- relativepath/~` will remove it. The `-r` flag observes whether a directory is empty, only then does it proceed. `-i` prompts for confirmation before taking action.

Comment: Are you sure about the `-r` flag?  Doing `rm --help`, it says:   ` -r, -R, --recursive   remove directories and their contents recursively`

Comment: Apparently I was mistaken. In any case, e.g.: `rm -- ./--woops` or `rm -- --woops` work. I distinctly remember a 'directory not empty' error thrown with `-r`, must be something else. Thanks ;)